# Unable to SSH from public subnet to private subnet thru' putty while creating a custom VPC

Tags: amazon-vpc

In the process of creating a custom VPC, i first created an EC2 instance and mapped it to the Public subnet and then created another EC2 and mapped it to Private subnet. Now from within the putty i could able to ping to my private subnet from my public subnet, but after that,i couldn't able to understand how to SSH from public to private subnet. Whether we need to copy the contents of .pem or .ppk file into the ec2 instance attached to the public subnet. I tried copying the content of .pem file into ec2 and also changed the access to 0600 for the .pem and when i tried to SSH from public subnet to private subnet, i was getting the following error as "warning permanently added (ecdsa) to the list of known hosts. permission denied (publickey)". I am doing all this from my Windows OS laptop and i created a Amazon Linux instances for Public and Private

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a keypair when you created the AWS instance. Assuming that you want to ssh from the public instance to the private instance, now you need to take the pem file that you downloaded and copy it to the public instance. Did you use ubuntu to create your instance? Then from the public instance console, you'll `ssh -i your_keyname.pem ubuntu@your_private_ip` If you used the amazon linux ami, then `ssh -i your_keyname.pem ec2-user@your_private_ip`. Now if you were intending something else, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think to make a copy of keypair file into EC2 Instance.
Use this command to login another EC2 Instance.

```
ssh -v -i key -l username instance-IP
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to copy the .pem file to AMI is using sftp 
try replacing sftp in place of ssh to connect your instance from MAC terminal and you will get sftp> prompt.
once you get sftp> prompt use " put 'your key name' 
and your file will be uploaded to AMI